# Get latest 2 records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table like this

```
ProdID              Code
--------           ------
 1001                A
 2001                B
 1001                C
 3001                D
 3001                E
 1001                F
 1001                Z
 2001                G
 2001                H
 3001                I
 4001                J
```

I am expecting output as

```
 ProdID              Code
 --------           ------
  1001                Z
  1001                F
  2001                H
  2001                G
  3001                I
  3001                E
```

Only to show latest 2 data. If any id has less than 2 data I don't want to show it (like `ProdID 4001`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
;With cte As
(Select ProdID, Code, Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProdID Order By Code Desc) As rn,
   Count(*) Over(Partition By ProdID) As NbrRows
From mytable)
Select ProdID, Code
From cte
Where rn <= 2 And NbrRows > 1
Order By ProdID, Code desc;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ee7f/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/152f7/1/0)

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY Code DESC),
        cnt = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ProdID)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    ProdID, Code
FROM cte
WHERE
    rn <= 2
    AND cnt >= 2
```

Comment: Your answer also works fine but  **Sabyasachi** was 1st to answer :)